# Azure IoT Hub Metrics Data

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

where would I get azure IoT hub metrics data?

I would like to get the metrics data on which alerts are set.I am able to find d2c messages but could not find metrics data.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view and create custom views of your metrics via the blade of your IoT hub.You can choose to send your metrics data to an Event Hubs endpoint or an Azure Storage account by clicking Diagnostics settings.Please refer to the document about [Understand IoT Hub metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-metrics).

The metrics define the summary counts of various configuration states such as Success, In Progress, and Error. Custom metrics are specified as queries on device twin reported properties. System metrics are default metrics that measure twin update status, such as the number of device twins that are targeted and the number of twins that have been successfully updated.

Comment: Yes, this is one possible way but I want to access metrics through REST api.

Comment: @GKAMESWARRAO, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-rest-api-walkthrough#retrieve-metric-values).The Azure Monitor API makes it possible to programmatically retrieve the available default metric definitions, granularity, and metric values from IoT Hub resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Azure monitor metrics rest api.

refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftdevicesiothubs) to get the metrics name from the first column. For example if you want to get connected devices *connectedDeviceCount* will be the metric name.

After getting the metric name, you need to form the api.

refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list) to get the metric api syntax. Since we have metric name, you can use optional parameter in the get api now.
Example for connectedDeviceCount:

GET [https://management.azure.com/{resourceUri}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=connectedDeviceCount](https://management.azure.com/%7BresourceUri%7D/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=connectedDeviceCount)

resourceUri for iotHub will look like :

IoT Hub - /subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs/{iot-hub-name}

refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/rest-api-walkthrough#retrieve-the-resource-id) for resource uri format

Don't forget to add the bearer token. you can use client credentials grant